# Isotope: prepend item

Tags: jquery, prepend, jquery-isotope

In addition to having an [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) with combination filters, I want to be able to use some links to prepend items to the Isotope. On the first click, I want the item to prepend, and on the second click of the link, I want the prepended item to be removed. I have gotten halfway there by calling a jQuery toggle, but on the third click - which should bring back the prepended item - nothing is called. I think it's a problem with how I've called my variable (mission_item). But I've tried a few variations, to no avail. The code I am using is:

```
var $mission_item = $('<div class="item mission">Mission</div>');
$('#mission a').toggle(function() {
    $container
        .prepend($mission_item).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order'});
}, function(){
   $container
        .isotope('remove',$mission_item);
});
```

You can also see it in action on my js_fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jessica_b/7uGDX/). The other thing that I am trying to figure out is how to get these prepended items to bypass the filters. I suppose I could add every filter option to the item's class, and this way it would always show, but I'm working in Wordpress and the filters are dynamically generated by the post categories. It seems like there should be a more elegant solution, but I don't know where to begin. I apologize for being a bit of a jQuery novice! and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the only thing missing is to set opacity on $mission_item

```
$container.prepend($mission_item.css({'opacity': 1})).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order'});
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I would have ever figured that out. This is why stack overflow is so wonderful.

Comment: Any ideas for how to get it to bypass the filters? I'm still stumped.